# Using sklearn model into pyspark for predicts

Tags: python, pyspark, scikit-learn

I have the pyspark Dataframe and trained sklearn model. I want to use it for predict using MapPartitions method from pyspark.

How can I write wrapper around my model for predicts?

```
X_test = spark.read.csv('path') # Dataframe with columns for testing model

with open('/Users/skv/Desktop/model.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file)
model_bc = sc.broadcast(model)

# I wrote function, but it predicts row-by-row

def predict_wrapper():
    def predict(rows):
            yield model_bc.value.predict(rows)[0]
    return predict

X_test_small.rdd.mapPartitions(predict_wrapper()).collect()
```

What I should change for predict one time for each partition?